# Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException with Apple M1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, apple-m1

I recently got a Mac Mini with M1 processor. I get this error when i try to run a project:
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException`.
The same app works on MacBook with Intel processor.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I heard that there are a lot of gaps in AS and M1 compatibility, that have no solutions for now. But you can use IDEA for android development, its works perfectly :)

Comment: There's a lot of gaps in everything and M1 compatibility. AS is working on patches for M1, but they're still gonna take a while to finish it. If Yegorf is correct and IDEA works on M1, you can use that. Otherwise, you'll have to bite the bullet and wait for them to publish a patch.